# Monitor all user events in Android

Tags: android

I would like to monitor all user generated events in an Android app. And I need to do it with as little modifications to the existing code as possible.

The "normal" way to achieve this would be use the activity's `dispatchTouchEvent()` and `dispatchKeyEvent()` method (from my understanding and experiments - I'm rather new to Android development). But this approach means subclassing the activity which is something I need to avoid.

Another thing I tried: registering a callback with `setOnClickListener()` on a view. But the behaviour I saw in my experiments is that if I register a callback on the content view, the callback is called for all clicks on views that do not handle clicks themselves like static text (TextView), but not for clicks on buttons, e.g. So in order to really monitor all events, I would need to register the callback not only on the content view, but on all views. This is also something I would like to avoid.

So is there a central place that all user generated events (touches and key events) pass that I can monitor without the need to subclass activities?

Comment: What would you do when you know of a user event? `Activity` class got `onUserInteraction` callback, but does not give the event info.

Answer (score 2):

We developed the Android HCI Extractor some months ago. It was made to track and monitor the user and system interaction events in multimodal applications (e.g. touch, keypresses, scroll, number of elements provided by the system, etc.)

It is an open-source prototype. Our aim is to share its code for developers to use it, and also try to get some help to improve this tool to reach a 1.0 release. Thus, fell free to download, test, modify, etc. the application. You can send your suggestions, help, code, etc. to this email: pedromateo@um.es

It is very easy to integrate and to use. In the tutorials you can see that only a few lines of code are needed.

Here the links:
 - Android HCI Extractor code: http://code.google.com/p/android-hci-extractor/
 - MIM project (including tutorials about the tool integration and usage): http://www.catedrasaes.org/trac/wiki/MIM

I hope it helps you!!

Comment: I tried to run the testActivity but I just see a blank screen.  How is it supposed to work?  Does your tutorial page explain this?

Comment: testActivity is just an example to launch the extraction tool. Could you please show me a code snippet to know what you are doing?

Comment: anyway, in testActivity you can find the 6-8 code lines needed to launch the extractor. It is marked by comments.